# 1 byte that represents different values in java

Tags: byte, bit-shift, nibble

I have one byte that contains Upper 4 bits are a bitmap for system status like 0x40,0x80 and Lower 4 bits values like 0,1,2,3. I do not know to parse them.Can someone help me.can I have anything like this?how byte will look like???will it be byte b=(byte)0x80?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: lets say I have byte b=01000000 I  need for upper 4 bits value only 0x40(64 in decimal) and for lower bits my value must be evaluated to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Bit masking. To get the upper 4 bits:

```
Upper=byte&0xF0
```

To get the first

```
First=byte&0x01
```

And so on.

Comment: byte b=(byte)00100010;
       int Upper= b & 0xF0;
      int  First= b & 0x01;
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(First));It bring 0 as output for Upper .